# Not able to connect to Vertica using Informatica Workflow Manager

Tags: database, informatica, vertica

I am not able to create connection to my vertica database from Informatica Workflow Manager. When I try creating a new connection, I don't get an option of vertica in list (See Image 1). But I have already installed vertica client driver on my laptop and have created a System DSN as well (See Image 2).

How can I set up a connecting in workflow manager so that I can run my first transformation using vertica?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: One more thing, I am able to connect to my vertica database when I am in Informatica power center designer, As I do get the option to connection to System dsn which I have created. But the same option is not visible in workflow manager.

Comment: This indicates there's a connection on Integration Service missing. While using the Designer, you use local machine connections. When running in Workflow Manager, the job gets executed on Integration Service server and the connections need to be set up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Informatica server installed on the same Windows machine, you have to create a ODBC connection object in Workflow manager.

In the "Relational Connection Browser", select type as ODBC and click on "New...". In the Connect String property, specify the name of the System DSN you created, e.g. PROD_reporting

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to fix this issue for a week and then gave up. Finally, I was able to resolve it with the help of your answer :)